# Running Specific Test for Meson Build

Tags: meson-build

With meson build, if I have multiple tests defined in the `meson.build`, like shown [here](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki/Unit-tests), is it possible to build and run a specific single test?  Lets say I am working on a specific module and would like to run just the test for that module using command prompt?

Answer (score 5):

You can give the name of the test you want to run to `meson test`.  From Meson's [doc](https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html#testing-tool):

> Specify test(s) by name like:
>
> `$ meson test testname1 testname2`

or if you are not in your build dir, do:

> `$ meson test -C builddir testname1 testname2`

A list of available tests can be shown with:

> `$ meson test --list`

As noted in [Unit tests](https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html) section of the doc:

> Meson comes with a fully functional unit test system

Your test will be run by Meson and by Meson only, meaning that there is no Ninja target for your tests.  Meson is the test runnner.

```
$ meson test -C builddir 'my 1st test'
ninja: Entering directory `/tmp/meson-test/builddir'
ninja: no work to do.
1/1 my 1st test        OK              0.00s

Ok:                 1   
Expected Fail:      0   
Fail:               0   
Unexpected Pass:    0   
Skipped:            0   
Timeout:            0   

Full log written to /tmp/meson-test/builddir/meson-logs/testlog.txt
```

`meson.build`:

```
project('tutorial', 'c')
e = executable('demo', 'main.c')
test('my 1st test', e)
test('my 2nd test', e)
```

If you are using a version of meson older than 0.42, you will instead need to use the `mesontest` command:

> `$ mesontest testname`

Comment: Worth noting, to point to a dir `build`: `meson test testname1 testname2 -C build`. And apparently you can't put `-C build` at the beginning as you usually do with `ninja -C build test` which is very confusing. And for some reason Meson doesn't create ninja rules for separate tests, at least as of `meson-1.2.1`. So running through Meson is the only way.